# Salesforce Platform Developer II Exam

Tags: developer, certification

I'm planning for Salesforce Platform Developer II Certification. How many steps are required for this certification.

These are 3 steps:

1. Multiple-choice Exam
2. Programming Assignment
3. Essay Exam

For this certification all these steps are required or number 1st step is required only (For this certification)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you check out [Salesforce certification page](http://certification.salesforce.com/platform-developers) and click the *Platform Developer II* tab, you will see the following:

> - A full exam outline can be found in the [Study Guide](http://certification.salesforce.com/SG_CertifiedPlatformDeveloperII.pdf?v=7)

So if you check out the Study Guide, you will see the following:

> The Salesforce Certified Platform Developer II program has **multiple components**. A candidate must pass the multiple-choice/multiple-select proctored exam to move on to the performance-based component. To earn this credential, a candidate must successfully complete all components.

So basically you have to pass all three of them, but you may only start with the multiple-choice

Answer (score 1):

Just an update here :

Salesforce recently on June 28th 2017 , made changes to Platform Developer 2 certificate. It now says:

> Effective June 28, 2017, the Salesforce Certified Platform Developer
>   II (PDII) certification will consist of two parts: a proctored
>   multiple-choice exam and four Trailhead Superbadges which replace the
>   Programming Assignment

Study Guide link - http://certification.salesforce.com/SG_CertifiedPlatformDeveloperII.pdf?v=7

Answer (score 0):

All steps are mandatory.

Mentioned in the Study Guide -

```
The Salesforce Certified Platform Developer II program has multiple components. A candidate must pass the multiple-choice/multiple-select proctored exam to move on to the performance-based component. To earn this credential, a candidate must successfully complete all components.
```

Ref link - http://certification.salesforce.com/SG_CertifiedPlatformDeveloperII.pdf?v=7